# Is there an R function to pull numeric values after a specific word?

Tags: r, regex, string

I'd like to extract the numerical values from a string, for example:

```
x <- c("14 trucks and 3298 pounds of tuna",
       "228 gallons and 190 pounds of sand",
       "161751 barrels gell, 3438540 pounds proppant",
       "29 pounds of hay, 100 barrels of water, 30 pins")
```

I would like to extract the numbers (numerical) only before the word `pounds`, and the result after the operation should be

```
c(3298, 190, 3438540, 29)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `sub` matching as few characters as possible until a number is encountered followed by "pounds", we can do

```
sub(".*?(\\d+) pounds.*", "\\1", x)
#[1] "3298"    "190"     "3438540" "29"
```

You might want to wrap `as.integer` to this to convert it into integer.

Answer (score 2):

If "##### pounds" appear only once in each record then this will use of regex will work:

```
x <- c("14 trucks and 3298 pounds of tuna",
       "228 gallons and 190 pounds of sand",
       "161751 barrels gell, 3438540 pounds proppant",
       "29 pounds of hay, 100 barrels of water, 30 pins")

y <- gsub("(^|.* )(\\d+) pounds.*$", "\\2", x)

y
[1] "3298"    "190"     "3438540" "29"
```

Comment: Need to convert y into numerical, :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you will have floating numbers in your data, so you can try the following code for general use:

```
as.numeric(gsub(".*?(\\d+\\.?\\d+?)\\spound(s?).*","\\1",x))
```

which gives:

```
> as.numeric(gsub(".*?(\\d+\\.?\\d+?)\\spound(s?).*","\\1",x))
[1]    3298     190 3438540      29
```

Since there might be some data less than `1` pound, then I used `pound(s?)` in the `gsub` for pattern